# Does the wave/particle duality exist across the entire electromagnetic spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, wave-particle-duality

Does the wave/particle duality exist across the entire electromagnetic spectrum?

If theory says so, then to what extent have physicists confirmed by experimental means?

Comment: The duality certainly holds irrespective of wave length. I'm not sure about experiments working on this.

Comment: What does it mean for "the wave/particle duality to exist"? *Quantum mechanics* certainly holds irrespective of wavelength or energy (as long as we stay below the scale where gravitation becomes relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Wave/particle duality is present across all particles, an equation to show this is:
$$
p=h/\lambda
$$
where p is the momentum of the "particle", lambda is the wavelength and h is Planck's constant. From this it can be seen that anything can be considered a wave, but they must have a very small mass to have a wavelength that isn't negligible.